# Perform SNMP walk using SharpSnmpLib BulkWalk method

Tags: c#, snmp, sharp-snmp

I am trying to retrieve the MAC address of a device that connects to the network.  My goal is to perform a WALK and then search the results by the port number that triggered the event.

I first grab the port information via a GetRequestMessage (Success).  Then I **TRY** to perform a walk to get the MAC Address table.  I do not get any errors or exceptions, but I also do not get any results.

Where am I going wrong?

```
// Capture IPAddress
string ipAddress = e.Sender.Address.ToString();

// Capture the port
string port = e.Message.Scope.Pdu.Variables[0].Data.ToString();

// Setup Authentication with password from App.Config
var auth = new SHA1AuthenticationProvider(new OctetString(_Password));

// Setup Privacy with Phrase from App.Config
var priv = new DESPrivacyProvider(new OctetString(_Phrase), auth);

// Setup username from App.Config
OctetString userName = new OctetString(_Username);

// Create IPEndPoint
IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), 161);

// Create discovery
Discovery discovery = Messenger.GetNextDiscovery(SnmpType.GetRequestPdu);

// Create report
ReportMessage report = discovery.GetResponse(60000, iPEndPoint);

// Setup OID variables to get port information
List<Variable> variables = new List<Variable>
    {
        // Port Description
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier($"1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18.{ port }")),
        // Port PVID
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier($"1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.4.5.1.1.{ port }")),
        // Voice VLAN
        new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier($"1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10895.5000.2.6132.1.1.1.2.13.1.28.{ port }")),
    };

// Create SNMP request
GetRequestMessage request = new GetRequestMessage(VersionCode.V3, Messenger.NextMessageId, Messenger.NextRequestId, userName, variables, priv, Messenger.MaxMessageSize, report);

// Send request and get reply
ISnmpMessage reply = request.GetResponse(60000, iPEndPoint);

// Request failed
if (reply.Pdu().ErrorStatus.ToInt32() != 0) // != ErrorCode.NoError
{
    throw ErrorException.Create(
        "error in response",
        IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress),
        reply);
}

// Store reply information
string Port_Description = reply.Scope.Pdu.Variables[0].Data.ToString(),
    Port_Pvid = reply.Scope.Pdu.Variables[1].Data.ToString(),
    Port_VLAN = reply.Scope.Pdu.Variables[2].Data.ToString();

// Create BulkWalk Discovery 
// TODO: Do I need to do this or can I reuse the original discovery??
Discovery BULKWALK_discovery = Messenger.GetNextDiscovery(SnmpType.GetRequestPdu);

// Create BulkWalk report
// TODO: Do I need to do this or can I reuse the original report??
ReportMessage BULKWALK_report = BULKWALK_discovery.GetResponse(60000, iPEndPoint);

// Variable to store the results of the WALK
var BULKWALK_results = new List<Variable>();

// Perform the walk and return the count of results. Community name from App.Config
var BULKWALK_results_count = Messenger.BulkWalk(VersionCode.V3, iPEndPoint, new OctetString(_CommunityName), OctetString.Empty, new ObjectIdentifier($"1.3.6.1.2.1.17.7.1.2.2.1.2"), BULKWALK_results, 60000, 10, WalkMode.WithinSubtree, priv, BULKWALK_report);

Debugger.Break();
```

**EDIT**

Also, I am using [this resource](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/tutorials/v3-operations.html#walk-operation) as guidance.

Comment: https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/tree/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmpwalk If it gives you the same result, do some further troubleshooting https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/tutorials/troubleshooting.html

Comment: @LexLi I grabbed the code from the link provided, compiled, ran in CMD.  It returned 244 rows.  My code above did 0.

Comment: @LexLi I found the problems.  See my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the issue, which was two fold.

The first was when instantiating the Discovery for the BulkWalk, it needs to be as follows:

```
Discovery discovery = Messenger.GetNextDiscovery(SnmpType.GetBulkRequestPdu);
```

The key part being getting the SnmpType correct (my code above is SnmpType.GetRequestPdu and not SnmpType.Get**Bulk**RequestPdu).  The [tutorial](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/tutorials/v3-operations.html#walk-operation) does not mention that the SnmpType is different.

Second, when passing parameters into the Messenger.BulkWalk() method I was passing in the community name and not the user name.  The source code remarks for the BulkWalk method does say community name but it should be the user.

I did as Lex Li suggested and complied/ran the snmpwalk sample to verify that there were no issues.  After that was a success, I went back and reviewed the source code for that sample and found the two issues.